# Updates on a bare git repo

Tags: git, repository

I have a single git repository on my local machine. When I'm done working on a feature, I commit and push the changes to one of 2 'bare' repos (production and staging).

The post-receive hook deploys the code after push from local. It works well, but I need to get any changes that happen on the 2 remotes (production and staging), such as when a user installs a new extension. I need to be able to 'pull' those changes to my local.

Should I convert the repos to each have a working tree? Can I pull the changes on the remote repos into the code base? I realise you may have questions about my setup but I dunno what you need to know, please ask. Thank you for helping me understand this!

Comment: I would say that you shouldn't change anything on the staging or production machines without changing them on development first.

Comment: Thx Patrick, I need to allow changes on the production and staging servers, so these need to be incorporated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the answer: you CAN pull from the repo in this instance. The key is; rather than push from remote, you need to pull to local. ie (on local):

`git fetch origin master:master`

Hope that saves someone else some time ;)